# wordpress-mu or drupal?

Tags: drupal, wordpress

I am in education and I want a framework that allows me to manage  the toolbox Teachers (Blog with features) and student blogs.
I want to choose between wordpress-mu and drupal, but I do not know which to choose:
here are my needs:

- multiblogging-user (one blog for each user for the site)
- gradebook (to grade Assignments for students)
- post-it (or to do list for teacher)
- I want to access the platform through a remote client (in php) using the protocol by exmple xml rpc

I just searched in google, wordpress and drupal. I realized that drupal for me because it offers such services module, gradebook module, and blogs module (which provides the default multiblogging)
I also saw that wordpress is earlier oriented blogging.
Drupal is he really the right choice?
someone else would be other compelling arguments that corroborate this choice

Answer (score 1):

While Wordpress has a larger userbase, Drupal is far more conservative about what gets into core.  The qa process is slightly better.  The end result is that writing custom modules and using the GUI as much as possible to make your system meet your requirement is a much nicer experience.

With wordpress is code horrors such as: a two similarly named functions but one with an underscore prefixed.  The prefixed function includes an echo statement while the other returns the entity. Bad duplication of code!
Wordpress 3rd party plugins tend to be nightmare to maintain as even with incremental releases of Wordpress plugin support may be broken.
Upgrading Drupal modules is usually alot safer!

I've heard good things about moodle too which is an open source project aimed at education institutions.

One of the main gripes about Drupal is that the admin is hard to use. Whereas Wordpress is much easier.  With the arrival of Drupal 7 last year, the Ux has improved significantly.
Wordpress has a great wsysiwyg bundled editor.  With Drupal there is none bundled.  I would suggest you avoid giving your users full blown HTML, and opt for a limited subset of HTML tags.  Ckeditor, imce, imce bridge and wysiwyg module will help you there.
Sometimes with Drupal 7 very popular modules are still only avilable to Drupal 6.

The only time I ever use Wordpress is when I need a blog and thats it.  Anything more then I go Drupal.  Anything more involved than that usually zend framework or similar.

Good luck!